# Размер иконок в menu

Tags: android-toolbar, android-menu, menuitem

Программирую под андроид первую неделю и впервые задаю вопрос на этом форуме
Подскажите пожалуйста как увеличить размер иконок в меню:

[image: screenshot]

```
Это код menu.xml

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">



    <item
        android:title="@string/add"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
        android:id="@+id/add"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />

    <item
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        app:showAsAction="always"

        />

</menu>
```

Код toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/toolbar_color"
    >

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Что я только не пытался делать:

```
<dimen name="design_navigation_icon_size" tools:override="true">40dp</dimen> //В файле dimens.xml

----------------------------------------------------

 <style name="MyTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/myActionButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/myActionButtonStyle</item>
    </style>
    <style name="myActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:minWidth">24dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxWidth">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:width">40dp</item>
    </style>

 android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
 app:popupTheme="@style/MyTheme" // применяя это в тулбаре

--------------------------------
```

Даже это внутри <item не помогает

```
android:layout_width="64dp"
android:layout_height="64dp"
```

Спасибо большое

Comment: исходя из своей *frontend`ерской логики*, я бы увеличил само меню, иконки заполняют его на 100% по ширине.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по [материал документации](https://material.io/components/app-bars-top#specs) размер иконки должен быть 24*24dp:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

можно конечно сделать увеличенный тулбар, но и там иконки должны быть 24*24:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вариант - засетить свою кастомную разметку в тулбар и там уже установить картинки нужного вам размера. Но это будет немного не соответствовать изначальной идеологии системы. Как засетить свою разметку [вот туториал](https://qureshi-ayaz29.medium.com/custom-toolbar-in-android-3818a0740942) и [вот](https://learnpainless.com/android/use-custom-layout-in-material-toolbar-android/).